# calling functions on subscript returnvalue

Tags: swift

Im experimenting with subscripts and generics, and what I am trying to do is this:

```
heap[0]!.hasLeftChild
```

Where my heap class looks something like this:

```
public class Heap<T> where T:HeapSubscriptable {

   private var size = Int()
   private var valueList = [T]()
   public var capacity = 3

   // subscript setter
   subscript(i: Int) -> T? {
       if i < self.size {
           return valueList[i]
       } else {
           return nil
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

To allow this i made a protocol extension:

```
public protocol HeapSubscriptable {
    var hasLeftChild: Bool{ get }
}

extension HeapSubscriptable {
     public var hasLeftChild: Bool {
        // return (self.size > 1+i*2 ) // <-- I want to get a hold of this i
    }
}

extension Int : HeapSubscriptable{}
```

But to calculate this I need access to the subscript parameter i, so that i can use its index in my array and do magic on it and see if it actually has a left child. Is there away to access it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "heap". My understanding, which is the same as [the wikipedia one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) doesn't match up with what you are doing here.

Comment: @JeremyP Im just browsing through some material,  here for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0Cq6tVNRBA, but forget about the heap part, thats not really the issue. Im just having some fun and found it more interesting to experiment with generics and subscript functionality. Thats what im curious about! :)

Comment: Generally, the value returned from the subscript method does not know (and should not need to know) at what index position it was located. You might want to rethink your design.